# getItemViewType() - How to return an int value

Tags: android, types, android-recyclerview

I want to implement a RecyclerView with multiple view types. Therefore, I use the `getItemViewType()` method in my adapter class:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position).getType();
    }
```

now, I get the following error:

> Incompatible types. Required int. Found String.

I know: It is because the `getType()` method returns a String instead of an int.

Question: How can I return an int ?

Comment: Which information is returned by getType().. Give some examples of the strings returned by that method

Comment: You are actually giving String . While the method needs an int .  Use enum and classify the views and then use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must "convert" that `String` to an `Integer` value.

```
public class CustomAdapter {

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_1 = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_2 = 2;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_3 = 3;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_4 = 4;

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        String typeString = mItems.get(position).getType();
        switch (typeString) {
            case "STRING1":
                return VIEW_TYPE_1;
            case "STRING2":
                return VIEW_TYPE_2;
            case "STRING3":
                return VIEW_TYPE_3;
            ....
            default:
                return VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_1;
                //bind viewtype 1
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_2;
                //bind viewtype 2
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_3;
                //bind viewtype 3
                break;
                ....
            default:
                // Bind default view
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply create an enum for your types, or local variables and return something like this:

```
    companion object {
       private const val MY_MESSAGE = 0
       private const val OTHER_MESSAGE = 1
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val item = mMessages[position]

        return if (item.isMine)
            MY_MESSAGE
        else
            OTHER_MESSAGE
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Use Enums to separate the items type in the view.
enum class RecyclerViewDataType(val type: Int, val desc: String) {
     TYPE_HEADER(1, "Header"),
     TYPE_DATA(2, "Data"),
     TYPE_FOOTER(3, "Footer")
}

// Model to Define the Data
data class DataWithHeader(
    val viewType: RecyclerViewDataType,
    val headerLayoutResId: Int = R.layout.header,
    val data: Data = Data()
)

var items: List<DataWithHeader>

//viewType.type returns the required integer a/c to the item.
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return items[position].viewType.type
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To deal with View Type in recyclerview, your ArrayList should have some unique type or they must be have the getType() function

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
  protected int mType;
  protected String mName;

  abstract int getType();
  abstract int getName();

  public static class Types{
      int MotorCar  =  1;
      int Bike      =  2;
      int Truck     =  3;
  }

}

public class Ferrari extends Vehicle {

  public Ferrari{
      this.mType = Vehicle.Types.MotorCar;
      this.mName = "MotorCar";
  }

  @Override
  public int getType(){
      return mType;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName(){
      return mName;
  }
}

public class Yamaha extends Vehicle{

  public Yamaha{
      this.mType = Vehicle.Types.Bike;
      this.mName = "Bike";
  }

  @Override
  public int getType(){
      return mType;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName(){
      return mName;
  }
}
```

So that when your getItemViewType gets called it will return type exactly you want based on your object type.